# Conversion between std::vector subclass with custom allocator and std::vectors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, subclassing, allocator

I have an advanced C++ question: Suppose I have a mmap_allocator
template class, which is a subclass of std::allocator template
class and a mmappable_vector template class which is a subclass
of std::vector template class:

```
    template <typename T>
    class mmap_allocator: public std::allocator<T> {
            ...
    };

    template <typename T, typename A = mmap_allocator<T> >
    class mmappable_vector: public std::vector<T, A> {
            ...
    };
```

What I can do is convert from a mmappable_vector (with an mmap_allocator)
to a std::vector (with the standard allocator) using a function template:

```
    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> to_std_vector(const mmappable_vector<T> &v)
    {
            return std::vector<T>(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
```

but the other way seems not to be possible:

```
    template <typename T>
    mmappable_vector<T> to_mmappable_vector(const std::vector<T> &v)
    {
            return mmappable_vector<T>(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
```

The problem when defining a constructor like:

```
    typedef typename std::vector<T, A>::iterator iterator;

    mmappable_vector(iterator from, iterator to):
                    std::vector<T,A>(from, to)
    {
    }
```

this uses iterators with the mmap_allocator and hence does not match
the call in to_mmappable_vector. On the other hand defining a 
constructor:

```
    mmappable_vector(std::vector<T,std::allocator<T> > v):
            std::vector<T,std::allocator<T> >(v)
    {
    }
```

fails because the

```
    std::vector<T,std::allocator<T> >
```

is not a base class of the mmappable vector.

How do I write a function template that converts std::vectors to 
mmappable_vectors? Is this possible at all within C++?

Thanks for any insights,

- Johannes

Comment: look up the vector constructor that takes a pair of iterators.  It doesn't take vector::iterators, it takes _any_ iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have template constructor in your `mmappable_vector` which takes two iterators of any type. Like this one:

```
template <typename T, typename A = mmap_allocator<T> >
    class mmappable_vector: public std::vector<T, A> {
      typedef std::vector<T, A> Base;
      ...

      template <typename Iter>
      mmappable_vector(Iter first, Iter last, A a = A()) : Base(begin, end, a) {}

};
```

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_vector.h

---

But the more important is that you should not define your vector like this at all:

```
template <typename T, typename A = mmap_allocator<T> >
    class mmappable_vector: public std::vector<T, A> {
            ...
    };
```

It is wrong because it derives from STL container, derivation is public and you do not have virtual destructor.

---

As far as I understand your question - you just need a typedef. There are two ways to make typedef in C++ - C++11 and C++03 ways:

**C++11**

```
template< typename T, typename A = mmap_allocator<T> >
using mmappable_vector = std::vector<T, A>;
```

**C++03**

```
    template <typename T, typename A = mmap_allocator<T> >
    struct mmappable_vector {
        typedef std::vector<T, A> type;
    };
```

Use it as:

```
    mmappable_vector<int>::type
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I understand it, I need the std::vector subclass because I have to add a method (mmap_file()) which modifies protected attributes of the std::vector class. What I am doing in this method is to set the size of the vector without initializing the content. The content for the mmappable_vector comes directly from the mmapped file, as far as I know there is no other way to achieve this. As for the destructor I do not have anything to destroy in the mmappable_vector class and use the destructor of std::vector (which calls deallocate on the allocator).

Comment: Please see https://github.com/johannesthoma/mmap_allocator for the complete source, I would highly appreciate if you can improve it. How do I write the constructor that takes iterators of any type (sorry for the silly question..). Constructor for `std::vector::iterator` cannot be overloaded and for the mmappable_vector it doesn't help because the iterators in `to_mmappable_vector()` are of type `std::vector::iterator`.

Comment: @JohannesThoma See update. You just need template constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never have thought about having a template within a template .. it compiles and seems to work now.